# VS C# CultureInfo set permanently to value within the IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cultureinfo

I've got a German VisualStudio 9.0. Working with doubles and doing quite some parsing, I came into trouble because of the decimal separator.

What I'm looking for is a way to either switch the whole IDE (and therefore all the projects created with it) to "en-gb" or do it project wide. I chose en-gb because of the lack of am's and pm's which I don't need.

I tried to set it by using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, but this regards only the one thread. Then I found the Application wide setting, which seems to be not what I'm looking for when developing console applications.

Any idea? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culture of the application defaults to the culture of the machine it's *running* on, not the machine it was *developed* on. The IDE is irrelevant here.

If you need to parse/format values using a specific culture, I suggest you do that explicitly - changing the current culture of all threads would be incorrect in almost all settings, IMO.